# How to approximate a light source as a point source of light?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, experimental-physics

A point source of light is "single identifiable localised source of something" (from Wikipedia). However, there are no true point sources of light in nature, since no object is as small as a point.

Yet, objects (like the sun) which are sources of light can be considered point sources if they are distant enough from the "screen". How exactly do I determine if a source of light is "distant" enough to be considered a point source of light?

Edit:
In another case, sources of light which are not necessarily "distant" but are considered plane (or non-circular) to some "small" extent could possibly be considered point sources of light (like a light bulb, with a tungsten filament, which is not a point). How do I determine if the sources of light (like a light bulb) are "point-like" enough to be considered a point source of light?

Comment: Smaller than the diffraction limit is probably a good rule of thumb. The Sun and planets are *not* point sources to the human eye, while the stars are.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can consider a source to be point-like if the error this would introduce is significantly smaller than other sources of error or uncertainty that would affect your result, or if the error is smaller than your required precision.

Take a sundial for example. The $0.5^\circ $  angular width of the sun is smaller than the error due to the discrepancy between apparent and mean solar time which can be as much as $3^\circ$, and is likely to be smaller than the error caused by orienting the sundial incorrectly when installing it without specialist equipment. Furthermore, you may only wish to tell the time to the nearest 10 minutes, and the Sun moves across the sky by $2.5^\circ$ in that time. Because other factors already limit the accuracy, there's no harm in treating the sun as point-like.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to calculate what the error would be between the theoretical result you would get if the light source were actually a point light source, and the result you will get from the actual light source. If this error is small enough to have no significant effect you can just treat the actual light source as a point light source in calculations. In most cases I think you would calculate the angular size of light source from the size of the light source and the distance to the light source. The smaller and further away the light source is the smaller the angular size, and the more likely that it can be treated as a point light source. The only example I can think of is that if the angular size is small enough that it could fit in a single pixel of an image being taken then it could be treated as a point light source, as there would not necessarily be any difference if the light source were genuinely a point light source.

One way of estimating the error could be to compare the expected result from a single point light source against the expected result from two point light sources each of half the magnitude separated by a distance equal to the size of the light source. If the difference is small enough to not be significant then you should be able to just treat the light source as a point.

Answer (score 0):

A “point source” of light is a source whose angular size is smaller than the resolving power of your optical system. Exactly what this means depends on what sort of system you are using and what you are using it for. In a sophisticated analysis is might be possible to distinguish mathematically between “smaller than” versus “much smaller than.”

For example, the Sun (viewed from Earth) has an angular diameter of about half a degree.  This might be adequate to call it a “point source” if you are doing shadow-on-the- ground type experiments. However, [even shadows on the ground can resolve details of the Sun’s appearance](https://petapixel.com/2012/05/21/crescent-shaped-projections-through-tree-leaves-during-the-solar-eclipse/).

Meanwhile, the distant stars all have angular sizes smaller than the human eye’s resolving power, so all of the stars in the night sky have roughly the same apparent diameter.  For a person with “good” vision, that apparent diameter is about one arcminute, or 1/60th of a degree. Next time you’re out at night and the Moon and stars are both visible, ask yourself: how many stars, lined up edge to edge, would make a line the same width as the Moon?  In my experience thirty-ish is a reasonable answer. (This effect is more obvious with a telescope, where increasing the magnification of a star cluster makes the pointlike stars look further apart without looking any “bigger.”)